# SQL Server : is there a way to insert into a table values using both SELECT and VALUES at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I'm trying to set up a trigger that will insert certain values from a table and specify other values with the `VALUES` command. Something like the code below:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(ID, Name, Email) 
    SELECT userID, userName 
    FROM users_table 
    WHERE condition1 
VALUES ('example@yahoo.com')
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to fetch first 2 values for `ID` and `Name` from a table and for `email` I want to specify a value.

Also I have an auto-increment column (called `crt`) in `table_name` if that is relevant. So how can I do this?

Comment: You can specify values and expressions with `SELECT` also, `VALUES(..)` is just a severely restricted version of `SELECT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `SELECT` and have a `VALUES(...)` clause in the middle of it - pick one of the two - stick with it.

So in your concrete case, just use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table_name (ID, Name, Email) 
  SELECT userID, userName, 'example@yahoo.com'
  FROM users_table 
  WHERE condition1
```

Comment: I didn't knew that typing quotes after SELECT inserts the quoted value. Your last example clarified everything

Comment: @Vantalk: you can specify column from a table/view, or SQL variables (`@emailAddress`), or **literals** (which is what this is - a string literal - also works for numerical literals like `0` or `42` or whatever) in a `SELECT` statement

Answer (score 5):

something like this,

```
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, Name, Email) 
SELECT userID, userName, 'example@yahoo.com' AS Email
FROM   users_table 
WHERE  ..condition1..
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(...)
SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM ... WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Constant1' AS Col1, 2 AS Col2, '2013-12-27T00:00:00' AS Col3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Constant2' AS Col1, 3 AS Col2, '2013-12-28T00:00:00' AS Col3
```

2)

```
DECLARE @AllRows TABLE(Col1 VARCHAR(50), Col2 INT, Col3 DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @AllRows (...)
SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM ... WHERE ...

INSERT INTO @AllRows (...)
VALUES ('Constant1', 2, '2013-12-27T00:00:00');

INSERT INTO @AllRows (...)
VALUES ('Constant2', 3, '2013-12-28T00:00:00');

INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable(...)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM @AllRows;
```